# Условие для отображения личных данных учетки пользователя

Tags: php, битрикс

Необходимо отобразить на странице данные 2х типов в зависимости от того, что за пользователь открыл страницу:

1) если обычный пользователь, то выводятся данные этого пользователя (битрикс учетки)

2) если пользователь из ИКС списка (по ID), то выводятся данные всех пользователей (битрикс учеток)

Вывожу данные одного пользователя по ID:

```
<?
global $USER;
$filter = Array('ID' => '28096');
$rsUsers = CUser::GetList(($by="PERSONAL_STATE"), ($order="desc"), $filter);
while($rsUsers->NavNext(true, "f_"));
echo $f_PERSONAL_NOTES;
echo $f_WORK_STATE;
endwhile;
?>
```

Каким образом написать конструкцию if/else, чтобы :
**если** id = 1, 2, 3 ... , то выводим данные как в примере кода (нескольких пользователей)

**иначе** выводим данные зашедшего пользователя (в моем примере просто меняется на GetID)

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я полагаю у тебя бд...
Забираешь все ID с бд для супер-пользователей и в условии делаешь in_array:

- $USER - я так понял - это текущий авторизованный пользователь.
- $listSU - Тут все ID супер пользователей.

---

```
<?
if(in_array($USER, $listSU)){
    // Это Super User
}else{
    // Это usual User
}
?>
```